# IOS App Development WebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7

I am trying to make an iOS app and I need to add a web view but the issue is I get an error:

> Duplicate declaration of method 'viewDidLoad'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

I am testing with google for now and when I develop the web site for the web view I will put the website in.

Comment: Side note - keep in mind that if all the app does is display some website then Apple will never accept the app.

Comment: _viewWeb.delegate = self.......

Comment: Thats not all it does its just one of its functions

Comment: Do you have two `viewDidLoad` methods in this class?

Comment: Yes i have here is a screen shot of my xcode ViewController.m

http://imgur.com/6FfYHCl

Comment: I am sure you have two viewDidload methods so try to remove one method

Comment: ur problem is well defined in the error log

Comment: What would the code be to declare it im not advanced at Xcode but i can generally use it but yea any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

objective-C does not support method overloading, so you have to use different method names.I am sure you have two viewDidload methods implemented in your .m class so please  try to remove one method

i have attached screen shot for your reference try to remove any one viewDidLoad method

[image]

Comment: Side note - Even in languages that support method overloading, you can't have two methods with identical signatures.

Comment: @rmaddy could you explain

Comment: In languages such as Java or C++, which support overloading, methods with the same name must at least have different parameter types. But a method with no parameters can't be overloaded because two methods with the same name and no parameters can't be differentiated.